# Socket server failed to bind to kafka:29092: Cannot assign requested address

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose

I am trying to create a kafka server from the following yaml file:

```yaml
version: "3.9"

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: 'bitnami/zookeeper:latest'
    ports:
      - '2181:2181'
    environment:
      - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes

  kafka:
    image: 'bitnami/kafka:latest'
    ports:
      - '9092:9092'
    environment:
      - KAFKA_BROKER_ID=1
      - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
      - KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - KAFKA_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://kafka:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      - KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      - KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME=PLAINTEXT
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://kafka:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
```

But I am getting an error:

```
ERROR [KafkaServer id=1] Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Socket server failed to bind to kafka:29092: Cannot assign requested address.
    at kafka.network.Acceptor.openServerSocket(SocketServer.scala:667)
    at kafka.network.Acceptor.<init>(SocketServer.scala:560)
    at kafka.network.SocketServer.createAcceptor(SocketServer.scala:288)
    at kafka.network.SocketServer.$anonfun$createDataPlaneAcceptorsAndProcessors$1(SocketServer.scala:261)
    at kafka.network.SocketServer.$anonfun$createDataPlaneAcceptorsAndProcessors$1$adapted(SocketServer.scala:259)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at kafka.network.SocketServer.createDataPlaneAcceptorsAndProcessors(SocketServer.scala:259)
    at kafka.network.SocketServer.startup(SocketServer.scala:131)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:296)
    at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:109)
    at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:455)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:447)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:227)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:80)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:73)
    at kafka.network.Acceptor.openServerSocket(SocketServer.scala:663)
    ... 12 more
```

What is wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is with binding the listeners.  `KAFKA_LISTENERS` is incorrect for the bitnami containers. All broker properties should start with `KAFKA_CFG`, as written in their README.

Also, you should set the `KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS` to use IP `0.0.0.0` to accept all traffic on all interfaces

Answer (score 3):

For what it's worth, this was the right configuration for me:

```yaml
version: "3.9"

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: 'bitnami/zookeeper:latest'
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes

  kafka:
    image: 'bitnami/kafka:latest'
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    environment:
      KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://:9093,OUTSIDE://:9092
      KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka:9093,OUTSIDE://sub.domain.ltd:9092
      KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_CFG_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INTERNAL
      ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER: "yes"
```